# forcing to close a file

Tags: c#, exe, handle

I have file that another process using it.
and I want to force closing the file. so that I will work on the fill.

I tried to use Handle.exe however it didn't find the process

would appreiciate some help here is my code:

```
 Process tool = new Process();
            tool.StartInfo.FileName = handlPath;
            tool.StartInfo.Arguments = _pathDirectory + " /accepteula";
            tool.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            tool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            tool.Start();
            tool.WaitForExit();
            string outputTool = tool.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            string matchPattern = @"(?<=\s+pid:\s+)\b(\d+)\b(?=\s+)";
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(outputTool, matchPattern))
            {
                Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(match.Value)).Kill();
            }
```

Comment: If you redirect the standard output streams *you have to read them*. Get rid of the `WaitForExit` - `ReadToEnd` is what you want. Also, don't just go around killing processes. That's just rude.

Comment: @Luaan It's not rude - [it's mean, man!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKHoMi-U8g4)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure, that if a program really holds an **exclusive access** to a file, it has a reason to do it. For example, Windows Explorer holds it when the file is in copying process.

Very often, programs open a file for a writing, but do not actively write to it. For example, when you open a document in MS Word, it is copied to the temp file and a source file is just "open for writing". You'll still have an exception if you use standard `File.Open` method, but you can copy it to a temp file using `File.Copy`.

Alternatively, you can explicitly specify `FileShare.ReadWrite` parameter and get an access to a file. In this case, other program will have problems with accessing a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mentioned the file name or type it would have been more easier, anyway try using the cmd for this. Get the process name and replace `ProcessName.exe` of the following code.

First you'll have to add `using System.Diagnostics;` on top.

`Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c taskkill /F /IM ProcessName.exe");`